# How can I select one radio Button of a Radiobutton Group when opening the Document? PDFBox 2.0.11

Tags: java, pdfbox, radio-group

I put a Radio-Button Group on my Document with the Code from the link.
When I open the Document, no one of the three Radio-Buttons is selected.
How can I make the second Button for Example being selected when opening the Document?

I use PDFBox 2.0.11 for my purposes.

[The Code I Used for my Radio-Button Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867139/how-to-create-a-radio-button-group-with-pdfbox-2-0)

Comment: Sorry this is confusing, you put an answer in another question that is a question, and in that one you refer to code from a third question, please include the full code in your question HERE. Apparently your problems are also related to having the same names in several pages or maybe not... please keep it all in one question, and put it all here. It should be mostly self-working. You can still have links.

Comment: I also made two changes in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807807/put-a-button-on-pdf-with-pdfbox-2-x

Comment: in theory, setValue("a") should do the thing...

Comment: Please see this response of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631119/radiobutton-display-problems-with-pdfbox