# Add calculation script to pdf form fields with PDFBox

Tags: javascript, java, pdfbox

Maybe someone can help me with this. I have a java application, which generates a PDF file from an HTML template using flying-saucer-pdf. Since there is no support for JavaScript, I'm planning to add my JavaScript after creating the PDF using PDFBox.

I want to add JavaScript to read a value from field A, calculate a new sum based on that value and write it to another field B. This calculation should take place every time the value in the input field A changes.

My problem is though, that I have no clue on how to add my JavaScript to the existing PDF file. I found this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_javascript_in_pdf_document.htm) online on how to add JavaScript, but it only shows how to register an Action to the opening event of the PDF. This doesn't help since I want to add calculations as described in the [Acrobat JS Developer Guide](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsdevguide.pdf) under Calculation script.

I guess I have to modify the Documents `PDAcroForm` somehow. There is even a `getScriptingHandler()`-Method, which seems promising, it's null on my document. My code to add the JavaScript looks like this sofar:

```
try (var document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
  var documentDocumentCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
  var documentAcroForm = documentDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm();
  var javascriptString = FileUtils.readFileToString(
                           javascriptFile, 
                           StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                         );
  var javascript = new PDActionJavaScript(javascriptString);
  documentAcroForm.getScriptingHandler().calculate(javascript, "99");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**>>Update<<**

Thanks to your input I have managed to achieve my goal of calculating new values. My Java code now looks like this:

```
try (var document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
  var catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
  var acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();

  var fieldActions = new PDFormFieldAdditionalActions();
  var javascriptString = FileUtils.readFileToString(javascriptFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  var actionJavaScript = new PDActionJavaScript(javascriptString);
  actionJavaScript.setAction(javascriptString);
  fieldActions.setC(actionJavaScript);

  var field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("fieldA");
  field.setActions(fieldActions);
  var coArray = new COSArray();
  coArray.add(field);
  acroForm.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.CO, coArray);

  document.save(pdfFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And my JavaScript code looks like this:

```
calculateValue("fieldA", "fieldB");

function calculateValue(sourceFieldName, targetFieldName) {
    this.getField(sourceFieldName).value = Math.floor(this.getField(targetFieldName).value / 2 - 5)
}
```

This works, although I stumbled on some weird behaviour, maybe I'm just misunderstanding the change event. With this code, even though I only added "fieldA" to the recalculation order, it seems that any change in any field triggers the event. What I actually wanted to achieve was, that only the change in a specific field triggers a recalculation of another specific field. Is this how the recalculation is supposed to work?

**>>Update2<<**

Ok never mind, I just made mistake and updated both fields on every recalculation event...after adjusting my JavaScript, everything works now as intended.

Just one more question, how do I add a JavaScript function globally to the document to then call it on field events?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also have a look at the examples UpdateFieldOnDocumentOpen.java and AddJavascript.java . getScriptingHandler() returns an interface, so if you didn't create a handler you'll get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the PDF level it would look like this:

```
//The text field
10 0 obj
<</AA<</C 12 0 R>>/AP<</N 100 0 R>>/F 4/FT/Tx/Ff 2/MK<</BC[0.0 0.0 0.0]>>/P 23 0 R/Rect[339.288 570.374 443.231 589.985]/Subtype/Widget/T(Textfield10)/Type/Annot/V(7)>>
endobj

//The JS function which writes the result of 'Textfield1'+'Textfield3' into Textfield10
12 0 obj
<</JS(AFSimple_Calculate\("SUM", new Array \("Textfield1", "Textfield3"\)\);)/S/JavaScript>>
endobj

14 0 obj
<</CO[10 0 R]/DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )/Fields[10 0 R 16 0 R 18 0 R] ...>>
```

So as you can see the additional actions (AA) attribute is the key to use. There are several answers in the web or here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331004/how-to-add-javascript-code-to-pdf-using-java-which-changes-listbox-content-based) on how to do that. It would look something like this:

```
PDFormFieldAdditionalActions pdFormFieldAdditionalActions = new PDFormFieldAdditionalActions();
PDActionJavaScript jsSumAction = new PDActionJavaScript();
jsSumAction .setAction("AFSimple_Calculate\("SUM", new Array \("Textfield1", "Textfield3"\)\);");
pdFormFieldAdditionalActions.setC((PDAction) jsSumAction);
```

Note that the JS syntax used here is *dobe JS syntax - so it probably doesn't work on other viewers. But that is the thing with JS script in PDFs anyhow and one of the reasons it is forbidden in PDF/A...

Comment: I got it to work, but now I'm struggling with some unintended behavior...I updated my question.

Comment: Please provide an example PDF or show a PDF code snippet (like I did in the upper part of my post)

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake in my JavaScript, I updated my post, the calculation works now as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example using Javascript to sum the fields:

```java
package com.danielcentore.formmaker;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionJavaScript;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAnnotationAdditionalActions;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            document.addPage(page);

            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
            document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

            PDTextField textField1 = createTextField(acroForm, page, "textField1", 50, 750);
            PDTextField textField2 = createTextField(acroForm, page, "textField2", 50, 720);
            PDTextField sumField = createTextField(acroForm, page, "sumField", 50, 690);
            sumField.setReadOnly(true);

            String js = "var val1 = Number(this.getField('textField1').value);"
                    + "var val2 = Number(this.getField('textField2').value);"
                    + "this.getField('sumField').value = val1 + val2;";
            
            PDActionJavaScript actionJavaScript = new PDActionJavaScript(js);
            
            PDAnnotationAdditionalActions actions = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
            actions.setBl(actionJavaScript);
            
            textField1.getWidgets().get(0).setActions(actions);
            textField2.getWidgets().get(0).setActions(actions);

            document.save("DynamicFormWithSumField.pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static PDTextField createTextField(PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, String fieldName, float x, float y)
            throws Exception {
        PDTextField textField = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textField.setPartialName(fieldName);
        acroForm.getFields().add(textField);
        PDAnnotationWidget widget = textField.getWidgets().get(0);
        widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(x, y, 200, 20));
        widget.setPage(page);
        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
        return textField;
    }
}
```

What the resulting PDF looks like:

[image: What the pdf looks like]